# Should I edit answer that contains religion specific phrases?

Tags: support, edits

I came across to this answer that contain few religion specific phrases. Are they allowed while answering or should that be edited?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56759428/3840213

Comment: Even if it wasn’t religious, that’s not even English. I have no idea what the relevance of _“, ma sha Allah, baraka Allah, alhamdulilah”_ in that answer is. It’s just noise and should be removed.

Comment: It's Urdu, but I also don't know what it means? *Ma shah allah* might be *the god is great* as per I know

Comment: If you decide to edit it there's lots of other things you could fix while at it, but voting and leaving it to be roombaed seems a better idea. There's nothing there worth spending time polishing.

Comment: In general, yes. In that specific case, no. The whole off-topic mess should just be deleted. It now has been.